# How do I get custom colors AND have my legend have the correct labels (ggplot)?

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, legend

I have a lovely stacked bar chart (see attached image).[carnival colors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gdm1R.jpg)

I used the following code to create this masterpiece:

```
    ggplot(data=data, aes(x=docket, y=Approved, fill=EMH_Cat)) +  geom_bar(stat="identity", position="stack") + 
    labs(title="Type of Study by Project", x="Project", y="Number of Studies") + 
    theme(plot.title = element_text(size=30,hjust = 0.5)) + 
    theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = 'white')) + 
    theme(axis.line = element_line(color="black", size = 0.5)) + 
    theme(axis.text.x= element_text(size=8,color = "black")) + 
    theme(axis.text.y = element_text(size=12, color = "black")) + 
    scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0,60,10)) + scale_x_discrete(labels=c("Bartletts\nFerry","Cabin\nCreek","Claytor","Emeryville","Green\nIsland","Jackson","Jennings\nRandolph","Keowee\nand\nToxaway","Loup\nCanal","Mahoning","Martin","Mason","Monadnock","Old\nHarbor","Oswegatchie\nRiver","Otter\nCreek","Salina","Tomahawk","Vanceboro","Wallowa\nFalls","Wells","Williams","York\nHaven")) + 
    theme(axis.title.x = element_text(face="bold", size=12,vjust=-0.5,hjust=0.5)) + 
    theme(axis.title.y = element_text(face="bold", size=12,vjust=2,hjust=.5)) + 
    scale_fill_discrete(name = "Categories", labels = c("Biota and Biodiversity","Connectivity and Fragmentation","Cultural Resources", "Geomorphology","Infrastructure and Design", "Landcover","Recreation", "Water Quality","Water Quantity")) + 
    theme(panel.border = element_rect(colour = "black", fill=NA),legend.box.background = element_rect(colour = "black"), legend.background = element_rect(linetype = "solid", colour = "black")) + 
    theme(legend.title.align=0.5) + theme(legend.position = c(0.09,0.7))
```

I used the read.csv function. My data looks like:[snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cHDK2.jpg)

The legend isn't in a fab place, but I can and will attend to that. However, the issue comes in when I try to add this little guy:

```
      scale_fill_manual(values=c("#1e7640", "#de772d", "#e815dd", "#7f6c00", "#000000", "#a03223", "#9e07f5","#2abdda", "#306ebe"))
```

These were the colors that were in a certain publication and so I need them to be in this chart as well. If I run the first code chunk and then add this guy at the bottom I get an error, Scale for 'fill' is already present. Adding another scale for 'fill', which will replace the existing scale.

It looks like this:[argh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/32Dcz.jpg)

I get why R does this, I just don't know how to fix it. I want to have my colors and eat the legend, too. HELP!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `scale_fill_discrete` with `name` and `labels` arguments. You need to give those exact same arguments to your `scale_fill_manual` instead, along with your `values`. Delete your `scale_fill_discrete` line and add

```
scale_fill_manual(
  name = "Categories",
  labels = c("Biota and Biodiversity", "Connectivity and Fragmentation",
    "Cultural Resources", "Geomorphology", "Infrastructure and Design", 
    "Landcover","Recreation", "Water Quality","Water Quantity")
  values = c("#1e7640", "#de772d", "#e815dd", "#7f6c00", "#000000",
     "#a03223", "#9e07f5","#2abdda", "#306ebe")
)
```

Comment: Never has something worked so smoothly. Thanks so much. If I could email a beer, I would.